# Strange behaviour with git status

Tags: git, version-control

When I modify a single file and then run `git status` I get:

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   app/models/category.rb
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Why there is the line `(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)` ??
There isn't file to add in my repo.

Comment: You might also enjoy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844161/git-status-a-bit-confusing. That question, also about `git status`, is a little different from your question, but you might find it interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git-add` is also used to add changes from the working copy into the *index*. The index is used to build a commit before it is actually committed.

See e.g. http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#how-to-make-a-commit

Answer (score 1):

You also use `git add` to stage modified files for commit.

Answer (score 0):

As the others mention, it's because git adds another stage to the process, vs, say, subversion.  The git repository's branches holds the committed versions of files, the git index holds the changes that -will- be committed, and the filesystem holds the actual current state of files.

Even if a file is already tracked, when it gets changed, it isn't going to explicitly be committed unless you act to mark it as "yes, do commit this".  A few ways to do this:

```
git add someFile;git commit; #explicitly add and then commit marked files
git commit someFile -m "  Change to someFile."; #explicitly commit a list of files
git commit -am "  Latest set of changes to all tracked files"; #shotgun approach, commits all changes to all tracked files or added files
```

I recommend using

```
git commit someFile anotherFile aWholeOtherFile -m "  Commit message."
```

Explicitly until you've really got a handle on committing in git and can be more aware of how to deal with dealing with accidentally committing something you didn't mean to, and then move to the simpler `git commit -am " Commit message."` approach.